# Scatter Chart, Ms Excel. points represent another data in another Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I made a [Scattered Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf1CH.png) for my Data in MS Excel.

DATA -

```
ID, Valence, Arousal
1, -1.15, 0.3
2, -2.25, -1.99
3, -3.15, -2.69
```

My Graph looks perfect, just one requirement, the points on the chart should point towards the ID, (i.e. when I click on the point, it should say, ID =1 or something similar, rather than values of Valence and Arousal).

I have over 1000 similar data points, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: The accepted answer on this thread has what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611447/how-to-label-scatterplot-points-by-name

Comment: Thank you so Much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Data Labels with the option "Value from Cells", as the link in the comment to your question suggests.

However, this feature is buggy and can produce unwanted results if the underlying data changes.

Rob Bovey's free add-in called "XY Chart Labeler" has been doing a great job for years and works with all desktop based versions of Excel. Download from the original web site http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm